# what on earth is wrong with my php code?

Tags: php, html

OK, making an api call with when acc=BURST-KHTJ-G3H7-LD2Q-H7LJ6.

This is the first array coming from `json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAccount&account=".$_GET['acc']))`

```
{
"publicKey": "231add65e7233e8df06debe3e71f161cb8975d21c9f9ee6e52f4868f524cb64d",
"assetBalances": [
    {
        "asset": "15295227971848272658",
        "balanceQNT": "4205"
    },
    {
        "asset": "11375670541237055652",
        "balanceQNT": "15"
    }
],
"guaranteedBalanceNQT": "0",
"balanceNQT": "5465615075791",
"name": "Irontiga",
"accountRS": "BURST-KHTJ-G3H7-LD2Q-H7LJ6",
"unconfirmedAssetBalances": [
    {
        "unconfirmedBalanceQNT": "4205",
        "asset": "15295227971848272658"
    },
    {
        "unconfirmedBalanceQNT": "15",
        "asset": "11375670541237055652"
    }
],
"account": "17456591454562991920",
"effectiveBalanceNXT": 0,
"unconfirmedBalanceNQT": "4870615075791",
"forgedBalanceNQT": "0"
```

}

and then the array from

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAsset&asset=".assetBalance))



{
"decimals": 1,
"numberOfTrades": 58,
"asset": "15295227971848272658",
"quantityQNT": "1000000",
"description": "Shares in BURST pool. See https://burstforum.com/index.php?threads/the-big-announcement.149/ for more details",
"name": "HardInvest",
"accountRS": "BURST-T7BK-USTG-KVKC-D2RDL",
"account": "13343849956527346993"
```

}

My code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $account = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAccount&account=".$_GET['acc']));
    foreach($account->assetBalances as $assetBalance)
    {
        $assetInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAsset&asset=".$assetBalance));
        echo $assetInfo['name'];
        echo "<br>"
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

But just isn't working, why not?

Comment: "it isn't working" ... could you explain **what** exactly isn't working?

Comment: Nothing comes up when i load the page. Just plain isn't working

Comment: You should probably help us by showing us the PHP Error. If the PHP Error isn't displayed then use the following code to display the error: `<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>`. On another hand, there's a typo in your code `assetBalance` should be `$assetBalance`. It's a variable.

Comment: Yeah, saw that, fixed it. With the display errors thing there is still nothing that displays.

Comment: Can you explain "what exactly isn't working in your code" ? If the JSON is retrieving wrong/different information, then most probably you don't have an issue with `json_decode`, `file_get_contents` and your loop. If that's the issue, your problem is related to the API URL and the parameters you're sending.

Comment: Well, I don't know, the page just isn't displaying anything. Is there something wrong with my server, because whenever there is any problem in my code it just goes white, like nothing is there. Even plain html elements don't show up.

Comment: Checked my api calls, they are fine.

Comment: Restarted my server, restarted the wallet(where i'm getting my api calls from), and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `assetBalance` to `$assetBalance` it's a variable not string if string add proper quoting for this

```
$assetInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAsset&asset=".$assetBalance));
```

if it's string try

```
$assetInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAsset&asset=assetBalance"));
```

Comment: what variable you need to send in inner loop get proper index from json

Comment: Aye? Sorry, complete PHP newby.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add in `$assetBalance->asset`under the bit with `$assetInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8125/burst?requestType=getAsset&asset=".$assetBalance));`

Obviously the other answers helped too tho ;)